# Python sqlite3: Diff of table in two databases

Tags: python, sqlite

I have two databases with identical schema and I want to effectively do a diff on one of the tables. I.e. return only the unique records, discounting the primary key.

```
columns = zip(*db1.execute("PRAGMA table_info(foo)").fetchall())[1]
db1.execute("ATTACH DATABASE '/path/to/db1.db' AS db1")
db1.execute("ATTACH DATABASE '/path/to/db2.db' AS db2")
db2.execute("ATTACH DATABASE '/path/to/db1.db' AS db1")
db2.execute("ATTACH DATABASE '/path/to/db2.db' AS db2")
data = db2.execute("""
    SELECT 
        one.* 
    FROM 
        db1.foo AS one 
        JOIN db2.foo 
        AS two 
    WHERE {}
    """.format(' AND '.join( ['one.{0}!=two.{0}'.format(c) for c in columns[1:]]))
).fetchall()
```

That is, ignoring the primary key (in this case `meow`), don't return the records that exist identically in both databases.

The table `foo` in `db1` looks like:

```
meow    mix    please   deliver
1       123    abc
2       234    bcd      two
3       345    cde
```

And the table `foo` in `db2` looks like:

```
meow    mix    please   deliver
1       345    cde
2       123    abc      one
3       234    bcd      two     
4       456    def      four
```

So the unique entries from `db2` are:

```
[(2, 123, 'abc', 'one'), (4, 456, 'def', 'four')]
```

which is what I get. This works great if I have more than two columns. But if there are only two, i.e. a primary key and a value such as in a lookup table:

```
bar  baz         bar   baz
1    123         1     234
2    234         2     345
3    345         3     123
                 4     456
```

I get all non-unique values repeated N-1 times and unique values repeated N times, where N is the number of records in `db1`. I understand why this is happening but I don't know how to fix it.

```
[(1, '234'),
 (1, '234'),
 (2, '345'),
 (2, '345'),
 (3, '123'),
 (3, '123'),
 (4, '456'),
 (4, '456'),
 (4, '456')]
```

One idea I had was to just take the modulus after pulling all the duplicate results:

```
N = db1.execute("SELECT Count(*) FROM foo").fetchone()[0]
data = [
     list(data) 
     for data,n in itertools.groupby(sorted(data)) 
     if np.mod(len(list(n)),N)==0
]
```

Which does work:

```
[[4, '456']]
```

But this seems messy and I'd like to do it all in that first SQL query if possible.

Also, on large tables (my real db has ~10k records) this takes a long time. Any way to optimize this? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replacing my earlier answer -- here is a good general solution.

Having input tables that look like this:

```
sqlite> select * from t1;
meow        mix         please      delivery  
----------  ----------  ----------  ----------
1           123         abc                   
2           234         bcd         two       
3           345         cde
```

and

```
sqlite> select * from t2;
meow        mix         please      delivery  
----------  ----------  ----------  ----------
1           345         cde                   
2           123         abc         one       
3           234         bcd         two       
4           456         def         four
```

You can get records that are in t2 / not in t1 (ignoring PK's) like this:

```
select sum(q1.db), mix, please, delivery from (select 1 as db, mix, please,
delivery from t1 union all select 2 as db, mix, please, delivery from t2) q1
group by mix, please, delivery having sum(db)=2; 

sum(q1.db)  mix         please      delivery  
----------  ----------  ----------  ----------
2           123         abc         one       
2           456         def         four
```

You can do different set operations by changing the value in the having clause.  `SUM(DB)=1` returns records in 1 / not in 2; `SUM(DB)=2` returns records in 2 / not in 1; `SUM(DB)=1 OR SUM(DB)=2` returns records that exist in either but not both; and `SUM(DB)=3` returns records that exist in both.

The only thing this doesn't do for you is return the PK.  This can't be done in the query I've written because the `GROUP BY` and `SUM` operations only work on common / aggregated data, and the PK fields are by definition unique.  If you know the combination of non-PK fields is unique within each DB, you could use the returned records to create a new query to find the PK as well.

Note this approach extends nicely to more than 2 tables.  By making the db field a power of 2, you can operate on any number of tables.  E.g. if you did 1 as db for t1, 2 as db for t2, 4 as db for t3, 8 as db for t4, you could find any intersection / difference of the tables you want by changing the having condition -- e.g. `HAVING SUM(DB)=5` would return records that are in t1 and t3 but not in t2 or t4.

Comment: It grabs them correctly but doesn't pull out the unique ones. Should the `HAVING` condition be different? I get `[(1, '123', 'abc', None),
 (1, '234', 'bcd', 'two'),
 (1, '345', 'cde', None),
 (2, '123', 'abc', 'one'),
 (2, '234', 'bcd', 'two'),
 (2, '345', 'cde', None),
 (2, '456', 'def', 'four')]` as a result.

Comment: Again, this should return `[(2, 123, 'abc', 'one'), (4, 456, 'def', 'four')]`.

Comment: Joe, from your sample data, shouldn't this return three records? (1, 123, 'abc, ''), (2, 123, 'abc', 'one') and (4, 456, 'def', 'four')?  The two records that have mix=123 aren't identical -- the delivery value is different.  (This affects the revised answer I'm about to send you). In Python terms, is this t2-t1 (set difference) or t2 ^ t1 (symmetric difference)?

Comment: Oh, maybe I wasn't clear. Sorry! I want just the records in db2.foo that don't appear in bd1.foo, not all the unique records in both dbs (a true diff).

Comment: OK, got it -- stand by --

Comment: It would be just a set difference, i.e. records in db2 but not in db1.

Comment: `select mix, please, deliver from (select 1 as db, mix, please, deliver from db1.foo union all select 2 as db, mix, please, deliver from db2.foo) group by mix, please, deliver having count(*)=1` works to get the symmetric difference returning `[('123', 'abc', None), ('123', 'abc', 'one'), ('456', 'def', 'four')]`

Comment: Got it. `select * from (select 1 as db, mix, please, deliver from db1.foo union all select 2 as db, mix, please, deliver from db2.foo) group by mix, please, deliver having count(*)=1 and db=2` works just like I want.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48420/discussion-between-chris-johnson-and-joe-flip)